# My app is crashed whenever I am using MediaControllers of a VideoView in android (on pausing video)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I am playing a video in my app through videoview. When I am clicking on pause button of MediaController, my app is crashing. Here is my code:

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
        chatVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
        mediaController.setAnchorView(chatVideoView);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(chatVideoView);
        chatVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        chatVideoView.start();
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

StackTrace:

```
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:626)
android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14957)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6764)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6530)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5987)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6054)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6015)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6188)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6245)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5991)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6054)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6015)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5991)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9028)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8979)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8925)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9163)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:276)
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:186)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8348)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1065)
```

Comment: Hi @Faizan Did you fix this issue. We're getting exact same crash report on specific android device (Vivo device, android 12) on Crashlytics reports. We couldn't find enough information about it.

Comment: No, I did it by opening video through some external players.
You can use external players or can use some Video player SDKs in your app.

Comment: thanks, you avoided using media controller and the crash did go away? if so can you suggest me a video player sdk? and did you have this issue specific to vivo devices?